# Can you give me hint in this problem????? I tried alot but it give me error and i don't know how to handle it well

Tags: c++17

The problem says: He has a wire it's length is N and he wants from you to count the maximum number of Squares with Length L can be created by this wire?.
Input: n,l
Output: maximum number of squares

My sol was:

```
#include<iostream>

#include<cmath>

#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  int n,m,sum=0;

  cin>>n>>m;

  int c=0;

  //int x=m;

  while(n!=sum)

  {

    int x=m;

    x*=4;

    sum+=x;

    c++;

  }

  cout<<c;

}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your solution? What is your input, output and expected output? Also please properly format your code.

Comment: you can find the bug in your code very easily by using a debugger. You need to invest time to learn how to debug if you want to advance in this field.

Comment: I have got this problem from codeforces , he say that input will be (n ) refer to the len of wire and( l) refer to len of side square and he want from me to get as output max num of square  i can build from this wire

Comment: As bolov stated, you should learn the basics of debugging code. However that being said I would also add that your solution is really over-complicated, I've edited my answer with a hint on where you should look for the bug. I would also suggest staying away from competition sites before you master the basics as they teach really bad (C++) habits.

Comment: Thanks sir , i understand what's my wrong from your comment...And I am trying to develop my skills by solving more problem in codeforces not more if you have any advice or recommendations for book  to develop my skills i wish to help me with this

Comment: @Mrxrobot I've updated my answer with information that might help you in your endeavours. We all started somewhere and I can see that you are willing to learn, hence I put some effort into the updated answer. So hopefully it will push you in the right direction. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is over-complicated. You have a wire of `length N` and you have a square with `side a`. If what you are asking is, how many times can I cut the wire of `length N` to be able to bend the pieces into squares of `side a`. Then using simple mathematical logic you get the following:

```
result = N [div] (a*4)
```

Where `[div]` means division of natural numbers.

So a simple solution can be produced by using natural number division e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    int wire = {42}; //This is N
    int square_length = {8}; //This is side a*4 so a=2

    std::cout << wire / square_length;
    return 0;
}
```

I either don't understand what you wanted to achieve or you are overcomplicating things using a loop.

EDIT: And to add, the condition in the loop is where your error stems from. Try to ask yourself if the condition `n == sum` will ever hold true for `n = 4*m+1`

UPDATE: Since OP requested some tips on how to improve his knowledge I decided to put the info in the answer (due to it's length).

If you wish to improve I would recommend to understand different skills that come into play when programming:

- **Analytical/Problem solving skills**
- **Syntactical** (knowledge of a specific language)
- **Experience related** (best practices, knowledge of frameworks etc...)

If you are interested in developing your **analytical/problem solving skills**, then any book on **mathematics** will help you. From the computer science world you could dive into any book related to **algorithms/data structures** (the key note being, that you have to try and understand why and how they come up with the algorithms and this happens only with a pen and paper).

One such book might be [Introduction to Algorithms - The MIT Press](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844)

If you are interested in the development of your **syntactical** knowledge, then any comprehensive book on a given language is what you are after. When it comes to `C++` there is one issue. With each new standard there is always a new "better" way to write code. But from experience I can tell you, that most companies are stuck in the `C++14` era (if you're lucky then `C++17`) and at worst `C++11`. Thus a good place to start is either `C++11` or `C++14`

For `C++11` people say a timeless classic is [The C++ Programming Language by Bjarne Stroustrup](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321563840)

The last skills that you can develop are **experience related** and as the name suggests - they come with experience. The only way how you can get them is to (for example):

- Be active in the open-source community (become a contributor)
- Work in the field
- Try to develop your own tools/libraries
- Frequently visit stackoverflow and learn from questions/answers that fall under a specific tag that you are interested in
- Read documentation/books on frameworks that you wish to use
- Most importantly though, realize what area are you leaning towards to (web servers, security, front-end, networking in general, etc...)